# Fastest way to kill NoSuchElementException or any Exception when element is not found in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception, nosuchelementexception

Is there a fastest way to kill the process in `catch` (when using try/catch)? Cos usually it takes 1 minute to make the process proceed after exception has been caught.

I have this code below:

```
public boolean elementExist(WebDriver driver, By locator){
    boolean exist = false;
    try{
        exist = driver.findElements(locator).size()>0;

    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return exist;
}
```

Whenever the script didn't found the element it waits 1 minute to proceed. I need to lower down the 1 minute to at least 5-10 secs bcos it's such a waste of time.

Or if there's another way and faster to handle *if the element does not exist* please help.

Comment: What's your implicit timeout? `driver.manage().timeouts().implicityWait()`?

Comment: will the implicit wait stop the 1 minute buffer if the element is not found?

Comment: Maybe, but if you have set implicityWait to 1 minute it's the reason why selenium waits for 1 minute before throwing a timeout.
So, what's your current setting?

Comment: There's no implicitwait in the method. :|

Comment: It's more like a global setting, not per method :)

Can you try to add `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` after creating new instance of `WebDriver` and let us know the results?

Comment: Do I need to add `finally` to the code to bring back the default of the implicitWait?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160210/discussion-between-rafal-laskowski-and-miel-yan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Right after

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //or ChromeDriver
```

ImplicityWait basically tells Selenium "Hey, every operation you are trying to perform should Timeout after 3 seconds"